# Python array operation. array plus array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of lists looks like this

```
a = array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.75612063, 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.65443227, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.70710678, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.70710678]])
```

what I want to do is to get a sum of those two arrays like below

```
output = array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.75612063, 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   1.36153905, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.70710678])
```

I can do a[0] + a[1]
but when "a" contains many many lists, then it is tedious to do so. Is there a function to sum all the values in the multiple same length arrays?
and then normalize the values(to make values in between 0 and 1) after adding all?

Comment: Do you want `a.sum(axis=0)`?

Comment: exactly. this works! thanks.

Comment: Looks like a 2d array, and you want sum 'rows', axis 0.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler example of what you are trying to do:

```
In [331]: a = np.array([[0,0,1,0],[2,0,1,0]])                                           
In [332]: a                                                                             
Out[332]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1, 0]])
In [333]: a.sum(axis=0)                                                                 
Out[333]: array([2, 0, 2, 0])
In [334]: a.shape                                                                       
Out[334]: (2, 4)
```